# How to read an excel file in flask webserver memory at the start of flask app?

Tags: python, pandas, flask

I am trying to generate a list of tools with prices. The prices will be present in an excel file. How do I go about so that the excel file is read at first and I will just use pandas data frame to perform search and get the price. Note I don't want to read the excel file again. I tried adding
`PRICE_FILE=pd.read_excel("./static/assets/tool_price.xlsx")` in config.py so that it gets read when the app is initialized but I am having some error. This might be incorrect, I am not very sure.

I am using a flask web app with sqlite as my database (flask-sqlalchemy)

Here's how my main and config files look:

main.py

```
import os
from flask import Flask
from database import db
from config import LocalDevelopmentConfig
from flask_restful import Resource, Api


def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__, template_folder="templates")
    app.config.from_object(LocalDevelopmentConfig)

    db.init_app(app)

    app.app_context().push()

    return app


app = create_app()

from controllers import *

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)
```

config.py

```
import os
import pandas as pd
basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))


class Config:
    DEBUG = False
    SQLITE_DB_DIR = None
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = None
    SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = False
    PRICE_FILE = None

class LocalDevelopmentConfig(Config):
    SQLITE_DB_DIR = os.path.join(basedir)
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = "sqlite:///" + os.path.join(SQLITE_DB_DIR, "toolcodes.sqlite3")
    PRICE_FILE=pd.read_excel("./static/assets/tool_price.xlsx")

    DEBUG = True
```

I also have controllers.py which handles the GET and POST requests.

This is the structure of my project:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YwB3g.png)

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation for pandas, there is a "pandas.read_excel()" function which you can use to read excel files.

The file can be read using the file name as string or an open file object:

```
pd.read_excel('tmp.xlsx', index_col=0)
```

or

```
pd.read_excel(open('tmp.xlsx', 'rb'), sheet_name='Sheet3')
```

Note: Reading the excel file in the Config.py file is a bad idea. What you should do is, create a route that expect a post request, then save the file in a local directory.

Once the file is save you can pass the URL for the file to the `pd.read_excel()` function to perform some logic. example is:

```
from flask import Flask,url_for, render_template
import pandas as pd
import request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/read/excel",methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def read_excel_files():
    if request.method == "POST":
       # URL we are requesting excel file from
       url = 'https://www.somelocation.com/prices.xlsx'
       response = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True)

       #Save the file to some location (example: "./some/path/prices.xlsx")
       file_location = "./some/path/prices.xlsx"
       open('file_location , 'wb').write(response.content)
```

Then read the excel file with pandas

```
       pandas_file = pd.read_excel(file_location,index_col=0)
```

Or if you are using flask url_for

```
    excel_file = pd.read_excel(url_for('static',filename='documents/'+ excel_file_name),index_col=0)


    return render_template("readExcel.html",title="Read Excel Files")
```

One you have successfully read the file with pandas, you can perform some logic on the file. You can also use Flask-WTForms to get the excel file from the user and pass it to the `pd.read_excel()` function

Comment: Hi  this route needs to be executed only once. Also I will just be pasting the excel file to my asset folder. I will not be writing to any excel file. I am actually using the pd.read_excel to read the excel file. Is there any way to use this only once. This excel file has the price of items. And items can be added or removed. I don't want to read the excel file more than once which is the case in case if I use a route and have pd.read_excel("filename.xlsx") inside it. Is there a way to read it only once like when app is initialized and keep it in memory till server is terminated?

Comment: Well if you say "This excel file has the price of items. And items can be added or removed" that will mean you will have to read the file every time new item is added in order to get updated values. Well I am not sure what you are trying to do, but if you only want to read the excel file only once then, you could try the following:      '

Comment: you have to hard code the file path within your code,                                                         next consider this  tutorial "Python mmap: Improved File I/O With Memory Mapping"  by Luke Lee   (Real Python)                                                                                                                                 https://realpython.com/python-mmap/                                                                                          I am sure it can help you